# on M5000, can i install only 3 domains?

Tags: sun

i am looking if it's possible to only install an odd number of domain in the M5000?

i have already check some links like this [How many domains can you configure on a Sun M5000 system?](https://serverfault.com/questions/50465/how-many-domains-can-you-configure-on-a-sun-m5000-system) and Oracle's documentation but all of them would say what is the maximum that can be configured.

i know the maximum is 4 domains but what if i only want 3?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to configure 3 hardware domains on your Sun M5000, you require 3 (or 4) system boards.  Provided you have 4 system boards, you can configure, 1 2,3 or 4 hardware domains.

Simply put, you can configure up to as many hardware domains as you have system boards in your server, and you can install a maximum of 4 system boards.

Comment: so 1 system board = 1 domain? then i should install 3 system board to have 3 domains?

Comment: @rino19ny Exactly.